# How to make a button default programmatically in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a small ios app and i need to execute a button action when user presses the 'enter'

In the apple developer site I have found this [article](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Button/Articles/MakingaButtontheDefaultButton.html)

and my question is where should I enter this

```
[myButton setKeyEquivalent:@"\r"];
```

Comment: u r develoiped in Mac application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

1. Set `self` (current UIViewController) as delegate for your instance of UITextField or UITextView:

   ```
   self.myTextField.delegate = self;
   ```
2. Don't forget to implement protocol `<UITextFieldDelegate>` in your controller **@interface**.
3. Then implement those methods:

   ```
   - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
   {
       [self.myButton performSelector:@selector(myButtonClicked:) withObject:self.myButton];
       return YES;
   }

   - (IBAction)myButtonClicked:(id)sender 
   {
       NSLog(@"myButton clicked");
   }
   ```